# Bus puzzle with stopping

Tags: probability

Question:
A bus runs on a loop. It takes to the bus 10min to  complete the loop. You go to the bus stop at random times, what's the expected time you'll be waiting for the bus?

Part 2:
Along the way the bus driver stops for 10 min with a 50% chance. For how long you wait now?

---

I think the answer for part 1 is 5 mins. I am confused about part 2. I think that 50% of the loops of the bus are 20 min loops and 50% of the loops are 10 min loops. This means that $\dfrac{2}{3}$ of the times I arrive, the bus will be in a 20 min loop, and $\dfrac{1}{3}$ of the times I arrive, the bus will be in a 10 min loop, so the expected waiting time is $\dfrac{2}{3}\times $ (expected waiting time in 20 min loop) + $\dfrac{1}{3}\times $(expected waiting time in 10 min loop) = $\dfrac{2}{3}\times  10 + \dfrac{1}{3}\times 5 = \dfrac{25}{3}$

Does this seem right?
Many thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. The second part is easy to get wrong by just assuming a short an a long loop is equally likely because they are equally numerous, but you are correct that you are twice as likely to encounter a long loop than a short loop.